# Why can't I add a gradient on map view?

Tags: ios, swift, mkmapview

I am trying to add a gradient on my map view but nothing happens. Am I doing it correctly?

```
let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
    gradientLayer.bounds = mapView.bounds
    gradientLayer.colors = [UIColor.black.cgColor, UIColor.blue.cgColor, UIColor.yellow.cgColor]
    gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
    gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 1)
    self.mapView.layer.addSublayer(gradientLayer)
```

Comment: Where is this code? Are you sure the map view's frame is correct at this point? Try adding the layer in front instead of in the back, just to be sure it works first.

Answer (score 2):

Three things:

- the CGColor issue DonMag mentioned
- you’re inserting the sublayer at the bottom of the map view’s hierarchy—if it has any other sublayers (which it does), they’ll be shown on top of your gradient layer. to fix this, use `addSublayer(gradientLayer)` rather than `insertSublayer(etc.)`.
- you should be using the map view’s `bounds`, not its `frame`—if the map view’s positioned anywhere other than (0,0) then the gradient layer will be offset inside it

Comment: I updated my code with your recommendations, but still does not work.

Answer (score 1):

CAGradientLayer colors are CGColors, not UIColors...

```
gradientLayer.colors = [UIColor.black.cgColor, UIColor.blue.cgColor, UIColor.yellow.cgColor]
```

Comment: hmmm... maybe try `self.mapView.layer.addSublayer(gradientLayer)`

Comment: OK - If you also followed Noah's advice about bounds instead of frame... sounds like you need to post a little more code. Tough to help if we don't really know what all you are doing.